# How to refact useRouteMatch according to the react-router-dom update to v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Hope u can help me to solve this problem! I'm a newcomer asking here so forgive me if I write something wrong.

Well, I've received a test for a job application and the purpose lookalike an old project of mine, it's a Pokedex basically, and I'm refactoring it in a new repository (I wanna use the packages at the latest version). It's been a long time since I've done the original one, and I was studying some other things so I wasn't focused on the react-router-dom updates and apparently useRouteMatch was deprecated. I've searched a lot about how to convert my old code according to the new hooks, but nothing showed up. So here is the code, made in React using Typescript:

```
interface PokemonParams {
  pokemon: string;
}

interface Pokemon {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  height: number;
  weight: number;
  base_experience: number;
  types: Array<Type>;
}

interface Type {
  type: {name: string;};
}

const Pokemon: React.FC = () => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState<Pokemon | null>(null);
  const { params } = useRouteMatch<PokemonParams>();

  const loadPokemon = async () => {
    const pokemon = await getPokemon(params.pokemon);
    setPokemon(pokemon);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPokemon();
  }, [params.pokemon]);
```

Comment: If you just want params why not use the `useParams` hook?

Comment: Idk how to use that one too

Comment: `const { pokemon: pokemonParam } = useParams();` then use as `pokemonParam` or `const params = useParams();` and use as you already have it `params.pokemon`. `useParams` should be available from 'react-router-dom'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useRouteMatch` hook was deprecated and not carried forward into `react-router-dom@6`. There is a [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-match) hook that I feel is the spiritual successor, but it's not a direct replacement. From the code it appears you are only trying to access the route path params, and for this you would use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params) hook. Coincidentally this is the same hook you probably should have also been using in RRDv5, see [`useParams` v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams).

Example:

```
const Pokemon: React.FC = () => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState<Pokemon | null>(null);
  const { pokemon } = useParams<PokemonParams>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPokemon = async () => {
      const fetchedPokemon = await getPokemon(pokemon);
      setPokemon(fetchedPokemon);
    }

    loadPokemon();
  }, [pokemon]);
```